# PCL Poisson Reconstruction

Tags: point-cloud-library

I have a `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloud`

Using `pcl::Poisson<pcl::PointXYZRGB>` and calling `setInputCloud(cloud)`

Then I create a `pcl::PolygonMesh` and call `reconstruct` on the `Poisson` object.

My question is what happens to the vertex data when constructing the mesh via `Poisson`, can I assume that the vertices from the original point cloud remains intact and that only polygons are constructed out of the original point cloud vertex data?

Hope I was clear thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The (reconstructed) mesh vertices are definitely **not** the same as the original cloud points. The new vertices are the result of running [marching cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) on an [implicit surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_surface) (that is calculated using the Poisson equation).

If you need to pass (interpolate) some data from the original points. You can use [nearest neighbors](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/kdtree_search.html#kdtree-search).

PCL does offer an additional reconstruction method which does preserve point location - [greedy-triangulation](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/greedy_projection.html#greedy-triangulation).